# The redundant threads of TEST and CMP in asm

Tags: assembly

I know that this question is asked a lot all over the internet, but still, I don't understand.

My question is, "Hey, what's the difference between CMP and TEST"

I know that TEST does an AND, and CMP does a SUB (Kinda)

But I'm not sure how it works...
Let's use an example.

```
[ EAX = 0000002B ]

test al,0x10
jne BREAK
jmp CONTINUE
```

al in this case is 2B, right ? What's going on here ?

I beleive it does something like

0x2B AND 0x10 = 0010 1011 AND 0001 000 = 0000 0000

Does the CPU sets ZF to 1 so it goes to CONTINUE ?

I'm confused, thanks for helping, all other examples are welcomed to make it better :)

Comment: Yes, you got everything right.

Comment: In the listing you have the immediate constant 10 (I assume it's a decimal 10, as in 0xA) and later in the explatation you have 0x10 = 0b10000

Comment: @Jester : Sweet then --- @VladislavIvanishin : My bad, i meant `test al,0x10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An AND (test) will see if **any** of the one-bits match between the operands. A single bit in common is enough.

A SUB (cmp) will check if **all** bits match.

Comment: Not to mention that `sub`/`cmp` can also test for _less-than_ and friends.